# How can I read text from a sign on PlayerInteract event after the new double sided sign changes with SpigotMC?

Tags: java, minecraft, spigot

I am trying to get text on a sign as a string when the player clicks a sign. Following the new changes made in Minecraft which allow signs to be edited on both sides, many of the old methods for doing this have been depreciated. With the new signs, you first have to getSide() before reading the sign lines. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem that the PlayerInteract event offers a method for returning a SignSide, with the closest thing being a BlockFace.

My current code looks like this:

```
    @EventHandler(ignoreCancelled = true)
    void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
        //Check that the player clicked a block
        if (event.getAction() != Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK) {
            return;
        }
        //Check that the block is a sign
        Block block = event.getClickedBlock();
        if (block == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (!(block.getState() instanceof Sign)) {
            return;
        }
        //Here is where I need to get the clicked face of the sign, and return a given
        //line on the sign as a String
    }
```

If anyone could provide a bit more info on how this could be done, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have requested this to be added as a feature to Spigot and will update here with code once this has been implemented.